# IOS - Can Smack API library for Android be used for IOS connect to Ejabberd Server?

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I want to connect to native a app en IOS to Ejabberd Server I work with the library: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework , but not have more support

XMPPFramework is very complete, they know some alternative. Regards!!

Comment: How do I ask a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you get anything?

Answer (score 0):

XmppFramework is better choice for implementation iOS app Side support, It can connect with mentioned server and can communicate with smack for android as well